# Type for Traversable that maps to same kind of Traversable

Tags: scala, types

**Short version.** Most generic collections in Scala have a `map` method which will, in fact, return a collection of the same type.  (`List[A].map(f:A=>B)` returns a `List[B]`, for example.)  The Scala collection library was explicitly designed to achieve this.  What if I want to write code that is polymorphic over any such collection?  Can "`Traversable` whose map behaves like a functor's does" be expressed as a type?

**Long version.** I have a situation where it would be useful to have an abstraction representing a collection of objects of some **C**urrent type, such that if those objects were converted to some **D**esired type, then the collection could use those objects to construct an object of some **R**esult type.  I can achieve pretty much everything I want just by using the function type

```
(C => D) => R
```

but one defect of this approach is the excessive laziness (in the context my application) of the natural `map` method, which would be something like

```
def map[C2](f: C=>C2): (C2=>D)=>R = (g => this(f andThen g))
```

This delays the application of `f` to the objects of type `C` until the `R` is being computed.  I'd rather apply `f` immediately.

So, for example, I might implement something like

```
class Foo[+C,-D,+R](cs: List[C], finalize: List[D]=>R) {
    def apply(f: C=>D): R = finalize(cs.map(f))
    def map[C2](f: C=>C2): Foo[C2,D,R] = Foo(cs.map(f), finalize)
}
```

So far so good.  But now I think to myself, there's nothing special about `List` here; any type constructor that implemented some kind of `map` function would do.  The only thing is that the function `finalize` might rely on the structure of the collection.  Maybe the first element of the list is treated specially, for example, so if the `List.map` returned some more general type of collection, perhaps a very abstract one that didn't even have a notion of "first element", then `finalize` could fail.  Likewise if it expects the list to be a certain length but I filter the list or something.

This kind of problem cannot arise if I write the code in its natural generality, something like

```
class Foo[+C,-D,+R,F[x] <: Traversable[x]](cs: F[C], finalize: F[D]=>R) {
    ...
}
```

because then I can't accidentally do anything weird with the `F` (unless I inspect its type at runtime or something, in which case I deserve what I get).

The only remaining problem is that `cs.map(f)` has static type `Traversable[D]`, not `F[D]`, although of course we expect that it's actually of type `F[D]` usually, and the Scala collection library was explicitly designed to ensure that that is so.

So my question is, can this requirement on `F` be expressed in the types?

---

Essentially, I want the Scala version of the Haskell code

```
data Foo f b r a = Foo (f a) (f b -> r)
instance (Functor f) => Functor (Foo f b r) where
    g `fmap` (Foo fa fbr) = Foo (g `fmap` fa) fbr
dothething :: (Functor f) => Foo f b r a -> (a -> b) -> r
dothething foo g = fbr fb where Foo fb fbr = g `fmap` foo
```

with more or less the same guarantees and without laziness.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for Functor from scalaz?

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Functor.scala

It allows you to do abstract over anything that can fulfill the type class definition.

```
def addTwo[F[_]](f: F[Int])(implicit F: Functor[F]): F[Int] = f.map(_+2)
```

Now my 'addTwo' method does not care what is being mapped, as long as there exists a functor instance.  So both of these would work:

```
addTwo(List(1,2,3))
addTwo(Future { 1 } )
```

etc.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I was hoping there'd be a way to do it within the framework of the standard collections library.