# Why does scala's `GenTraversableOnce` not declare `map`?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

[`GenTraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.html) does not declare `map` as an (abstract) member, but both its direct children [`GenTraversable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/GenTraversable.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):Traversable[B]) and [`TraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.TraversableOnce[B]) do (although the latter does so using implicit conversion). Why?

If I need a collection that implements `map`, what type should I declare it?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572929/type-for-traversable-that-maps-to-same-kind-of-traversable) is quite different as it asks for a way to implement a functor in Scala, while I am inquiring about details of the Scala collection framework.

**EDIT**
It has nothing to do with how many times you can traverse a `GenTraversableOnce` as `TraversableOnce` makes the same promises regarding the number of possible traversals (i.e. both promise at least one traversal).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type for Traversable that maps to same kind of Traversable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572929/type-for-traversable-that-maps-to-same-kind-of-traversable)

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember seeing this anywhere, but here is my intuition about it(don't have any references/citations so take this with a grain of salt).

As the name for `GenTraversableOnce` implies this trait only guarantees *one* iteration over the contents of a traversable.

The `map` operations somewhat implies the potential of chaining transformations (e.g. `foo.map(f).map(g)`) which means multiple traversals.

Comment: I don't think this is a satisfying answer: mapping twice does not imply multiple traversals, as the application of the mapped functions can be delayed until `foo.map(f).map(g)` is traversed. In other words: as long as `foo.map(f)` only returns a(nother) `GenTraversableOnce`, multiple transformations do not mean multiple iterations.

Moreover: `TraversableOnce` also implies only one iteration is guaranteed, while it _does_ declare `map`.